# How to Integrate Django WEB Application with Microsoft Azure For Authentication

Tags: python, django, azure, authentication, single-sign-on

I have developed a web application based on Django Framework, but i want my application to get authenticated by Azure Single Sign on, Please suggest the method or tutorials to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Google `django azure authentication` leads to [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-microsoft-auth/) leads to [here](https://github.com/AngellusMortis/django_microsoft_auth)
Documentation [here](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/)